# Creating a cumulative distribution from a vector

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution

I need to create a cumulative distribution from some numbers contained in a vector. The vector counts the number of times a dot product operation occurs in an algorithm I've been given.

An example vector would be

```
myVector = [100 102 101 99 98 100 101 110 102 101 100 99]
```

I'd like to plot the probability that I have fewer than 99 dot products, against a range from 0 to 120. The built in function

```
Cumdist(MyVector)
```

Isn't appropriate as I need to plot over a wider range than cumdist currently provides.

I've tried using

```
plot([0 N],cumsum(myVector))
```

but I have multiple entries which are the same value in my vector, and I can't work out how not to double count.

Here is some python code which does what I want:

```
count = [x[0] for x in tests]
found = [x[1] for x in tests]
found.sort()
num = Counter(found)
freqs = [x for x in num.values()]
cumsum = [sum(item for item in freqs[0:rank+1]) for rank in xrange(len(freqs))]
normcumsum  = [float(x)/numtests for x in cumsum]
```

tests is a list of numbers representing the number of times a dot product was done.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

[Example cumulative distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v6pJ.png)

Comment: Can you please add more information? An example would give us more insight.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I think duplicates should give higher increases than single values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a cumulative distribution, you cannot use `cumsum` on the vector directly. Do the following instead:

```
sortedVector = sort(myVector(:));
indexOfValueChange = [find(diff(sortedVector));true];
relativeCounts = (1:length(sortedVector))/length(sortedVector);

plot(sortedVector(indexOfValueChange),relativeCounts(indexOfValueChange))
```

**EDIT**

If your goal is just to modify the x-range of your plot,

```
xlim([0 120])
```

should do what you need.

Comment: How would I change the x-axis to go from 0 to 150, say?

Comment: It seems you miss the highest value if you use `diff`. You could replace `diff(sortedVector)` with something like `diff([sortedVector; Inf])`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin may be right. At a minimum the result differs from that returned by Matlab's `ecdf` function.

Answer (score 2):

Five hours and an answer already accepted, but if you're still interested in another answer...

What you're trying to do is obtain the [empirical CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) of your data. Matlab's Statistics Toolbox, which you likely have, has a function to do exactly this in a statistically careful manner: [`ecdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html). So all you actually need to do is

```
myVector = [100 102 101 99 98 100 101 110 102 101 100 99];
[Y,X] = ecdf(myVector);
figure;
plot(X,Y);
```

You can use [`stairs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) instead of `plot` to display the true shape of the empirical distribution.

Comment: Felt that something was not right, but didn't think about stairs. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
myVector = [100 102 101 99 98 100 101 110 102 101 100 99];
N = numel(myVector);
x = sort(myVector);
y = 1:N;
[xplot , idx] = unique(x,'last')
yplot = y(idx)/N
stairs(xplot,yplot)

%Optionally
xfull = [0 xplot 120]
yfull = [0 yplot 1]
stairs(xfull,yfull)
```

Comment: Your "Optionally" case is identical to what `ecdf` returns in this case, except that `xfull(1)` should be 98 (`min(myVector)`), not 0.

Comment: @horchler I don't understand, before you observe something the empirical distribution will be 0.

Comment: I think the point of an empirical CDF is that it only takes on values present in the data. It assumes that the minimum data value corresponds to the lower bound of the distribution and similar for the maximum data value. In this case there is no data to show that `0` is even contained in the support of the distribution.

Comment: @horchler It only has steps at data value points and may therefore often not be drawn outside the min and max values. However it is definitely defined. When looking at the [definition on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function#Definition) you will find that the domain of any ECDF is the entire set of real numbers.

Comment: I stand corrected about the domain, but then, under Gaussian assumptions `-Inf` would be a better choice than `0` for `xfull` if the ECDF is evaluated at `yfull=0`.